# Is it possible to send liberty batch logs to console

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Liberty has rich support for logging and tracing as outlined in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Based on that, I am able to get audit, messaging, and trace logs sent to the console.  However, one part of our system is using Liberty's JBatch implementation and these logs are getting lost inside our containers' ephemeral filesystem.

Is there a way to force Liberty to send these logs to the console with the rest of our output (so that it will get shipped to our log analysis service)?

Comment: I'd suggest opening a "Feature Request" on Open Liberty Batch here:  https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/new/choose.    Though the batch job logs are accessible via REST API, there isn't an easy way to collect them.    You could mention there too what mechanism(s) you're using to collect the rest of the output.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/13158